# Question about Scala variable Mutability

Tags: scala, immutability

I understand that **val** keyword determines the underlying variable is a Immutable type (Cannot be reassigned later time). Now i come across a paragraph in programming in scala (Chapter 3, Next steps in scala - parameterize arrays with types), it states

```
val greetStrings: Array[String] = new Array[String](3)
greetStrings(0) = "Hello"
greetStrings(1) = ", "
greetStrings(2) = "world!\n"
```

> These three lines of code illustrate
>   an important concept to understand
>   about Scala concerning the meaning of
>   val. When you define a variable with
>   val, the variable can’t be reassigned,
>   but the object to which it refers
>   could potentially still be changed. So
>   in this case, you couldn’t reassign
>   greetStrings to a different array;
>   greetStrings will always point to the
>   same Array[String] instance with which
>   it was initialized. But you can change
>   the elements of that Array[String]
>   over time, so the array itself is
>   mutable.

so its valid to change the elements of array. And its invalid if we define like this

```
greetStrings = Array("a","b","c")
```

It satisfies the below statement

> When you define a variable with
>   val, the variable can’t be reassigned,
>   but the object to which it refers
>   could potentially still be changed.

but if i declare something like this

```
val str = "immutable string"
```

By the definition given in the book

what it means **object to which it refers could potentially still be changed** in the above line of code ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declaring a **val** does not guarantee or even imply an immutable type. It only declares what you might call in Java a **final** variable. The identifier cannot be re-assigned, but the value may be of a mutable type.

In your example of a string value, you have both a **val** and an immutable type, String. So this identifier is neither re-assignable nor modifiable (immutable).

Comment: thanks Elmo.. So "object to which it refers could potentially still be changed" only applicable for arrays declared with val(immutable).... ??

Comment: Hi Ramesh. In Scala, Array is mutable (but you can't change it's length). If you want an immutable implementation of a collection, you could try List.

Comment: List exists in both a mutable and immutable version. The mutable version is called ListBuffer. Compare with String and StringBuffer/StringBuilder in java, where String is immutable and StringBuffer/StringBuilder is mutable. 


See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241166/preferred-way-to-create-a-scala-list

Comment: Note that `List` is *not* the same kind of thing as an immutable `Array`. A `List` behaves like a linked list - you do not have effient random access like in an array. If you need an immutable array, use `scala.collections.immutable.IndexedSeq`.