# What's the best way to create a dynamically growing array in Scala?

Tags: scala

I wanted to add items dynamically into an array. But it seems Scala arrays and lists don't provide any methods for adding items dynamically due to the immutable nature.

So I decided to use List data type to make use of this **::** method to achieve this. My code look like this

```
var outList = List(Nil)
val strArray = Array("ram","sam","bam")

for (str<-strArray)
     outList = str :: outList
```

Though it works in some way, the problem is the new strings are pre-appended into the list. But the ideal requirement is order of the data. Yeah, I know what you are thinking, you can reverse the final result list to get the original order. But the problem is it's a huge array. And I believe it's not a solution though it solves the problem. I believe there should be a simple way to solve this...

And my reason for hacking Scala is to learn the functional way of coding. Having **var** (mutable type) and populating the list on the fly seems to me is not a functional way of solving things.

How can I do it?

Ideally, I want to achieve something like this in Scala (below the [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) code)

```
List<int> ls = new List<int>();    
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    ls.Add(i);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> But it seems Scala Arrays & Lists doesn't provide any methods for adding items dynamically due to the immutable nature.

Well, no. Scala Arrays are just Java arrays, so they *are* mutable:

```
val arr = Array(1,2)

arr(0) = 3 // arr == Array(3, 2)
```

But just as Java (and C/C++/C#/etc.) arrays, you can't change *the size* of an array.

So you need another collection, which is backed by an array, but does allow resizing. A suitable collection in Scala is [`scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html), [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in Java, etc.

If you want to get a `List` instead of an `Array` in the end, use [`scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work with immutable structures, you can use the ++ method:

```
scala> val orgList = List(1,2,3)
orgList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val list2Add = List(4,5,6)
list2Add: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> val newList = orgList ++ list2Add
newList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

If you want to do more work on the elements than just adding them you can use higher order functions:

```
val newList = orgList ++ list2Add.map(_ * 2)
newList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 12)
```

Or with a for loop:

```
val newList = orgList ++ {for(x <- list2Add) yield 2*x}
```

Or you could create some recursive loop:

```
def addAll(toList: List[Int], fromList: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  fromList match {
    case x :: tail => addAll(2*x :: toList, tail)
    case Nil => toList
  }

val newList = addAll(orgList, list2Add )
```

but in this case the ordering of the added elements will be in reversed:

```
List(12, 10, 8, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you want performance when working with lists, it is better to reverse the result than try to add new elements in the end. Adding elements in the end to a list is nooot good :-)

Comment: thats not requirement... i want to populate the list on the fly". the size is unknown. It could be anything based on the incoming data.. i have updated my question for more clarity

Answer (score 4):

Going after retronym's answer:

If you still want to use list there are a few ways to prepend an item to the list. What you can do is (yes the top part is still wrong):

```
scala> var outList : List[String] = Nil
outList: List[String] = List()

scala> val strArray = Array("a","b","c")
strArray: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> for(s <- strArray)      
     | outList = outList :+ s

scala> outList
res2: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

Note the :+ operator. If you rather append, you'd use s +: outList.

Now who says programming in Scala isn't fun? ;)

P.S. Maybe the reason why you'd want to make them immutable is the speed. Handling large data will be more efficient with immutable data types. Am I right?

Comment: Note that `for(s <- strArray) { outList = outList :+ s }` takes quadratic time.

Comment: Ahh, bugger! Really? What about outList ::: s? Do you have any reference of the complexity of scala functions? I tried googling didn't find anything.

From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241166/preferred-way-to-create-a-scala-list I think the general consensus is to prepend and reverse.

Comment: Same. `List` is an immutable linked list, so appending 1 element to one -- whatever method you use -- _has to_ take linear time (since you have to copy all of its elements), so this loop takes quadratic time. Appending to `ListBuffer` and calling `toList` is better than prepending and reversing, but prepending and reversing is _much_ better than appending to a `List`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a mutable Buffer, as retronym mentioned. It looks like this:

```
scala> var outList = scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String]()
outList: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> for(str<-strArray) outList += str                          

scala> outList
res10: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(ram, sam, bam)
```

Anyway, perhaps it is better to directly do the things you want to do with the `strArray`. E.g:

```
strArray map(_.toUpperCase) foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there are a few things to clear up.

This is wrong, you're make a one element list, containing an empty list:

```
scala> var outList = List(Nil) 
outList: List[object Nil] = List(List())
```

`Nil` is the empty list:

```
scala> var outList: List[String] = Nil
outList: List[String] = List()
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
scala> var outList = List[String]() 
outList: List[String] = List()
```

Without more context, it's hard to know what you mean by 'dynamically'. Your example code would be better written as:

```
scala> val strArray = Array("ram","sam","bam")
strArray: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(ram, sam, bam)

scala> strArray toList
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(ram, sam, bam)
```

If you want a mutable collection that can grow and efficiently handle prepend, append, and insert operations, you could use [`scala.mutable.Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html).

Comment: dynamically in the sense "i want to populate the list on the fly". the size is unknown. It could be anything based on the incoming data.. i have updated my question for more clarity

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to create a new collection, you can use the yield key word:

```
val outlist = for(i <- 0 to 100) yield i
```

Or:

```
val arrList = "Some" :: "Input" :: "List" :: Nil
val outlist = for ( i <- arrList ) yield i
```

Technically, outlist is a Seq in both of the above examples so you may need to call the toList method on it if you need some of List's methods.

Comment: You don't even need to say `for(i <- 0 to 100) yield i`.  You can just say `(0 to 100)` and, if desired, convert it to a different collection with the `.toList` method or such.

Answer (score 1):

We can use ArrayBuffer as suggested. 
However, i have created a simple program which takes no of parameters for an Array of int and it will let you enter the numbers and finally we are displaying them.

```
val arraySize = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt
  val arr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]() ++ (1 to arraySize).map{
    i =>
      scala.io.StdIn.readLine().toInt
  }
  println(arr.mkString(","))
```